# How to insert a timestamp string into postgres db with psycopg?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, psycopg2

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_WITH_A_TIMESTAMP
(
   TIMESTAMP_ID varchar(4),
   TIMESTAMP timestamp
)
```

and an `INSERT` command that works with other tools:
`INSERT INTO "my_schema"."table_with_a_timestamp" (timestamp_id, timestamp) VALUES ('0001', {ts '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001'});`

Now I want to use psycopg2 to execute this command on my table.

```
query = """INSERT INTO "my_schema"."table_with_a_timestamp" (timestamp_id, timestamp) VALUES ('0001', {ts '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001'});"""
cursor.execute(query)
```

This does not work, the error message is:

```
syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...rsion) VALUES ('0001',{ts '2020-...
                                                             ^
: ProgrammingError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 35, in lambda_handler
    cursor.execute(query)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "{"
LINE 1: ...rsion) VALUES ('0001',{ts '2020-...
```

There are similar questions dealing with timestamps as python objects. However I would prefer not to parse the command, convert to a python timestamp and then do string interpolation. Since I'm reading the command from a file anyway I would much prefer to just bring the command in the right format (not necessarily in python).
What is the right format for a string command above so that it writes the timestamp to a table?

I've tried:
`"""...,'ts {2020-01-01 00:00:00.001}',  ..."""` -> invalid input syntax for type timestamp
`"""...,"ts {'2020-01-01 00:00:00.001'}",  ..."""` -> column "{ts '2001-08-13 10:19:47.701'}" does not exist
`"""...,ts '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001',  ..."""` -> type "ts" does not exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `{ts '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001'}` is specific for *the other tools.* Postgres correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO "my_schema"."table_with_a_timestamp" (timestamp_id, timestamp) 
VALUES ('0001', timestamp '2020-01-01 00:00:00.001');
```

though the word `timestamp` is not necessary in this case, see [Db<>Fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=67f38e035acb68b66bac383dafcad362)